# Is this class deprecated, or just the constructors. How does that work

Tags: java, class, methods, jar, jms

I am reading this site, which says the contructors are deprecated.

Does this mean the entire classis deprecated ?

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc%2FWMQJMSClasses%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fmq%2Fjms%2FMQConnectionMetaData.html

Thanks

Comment: It tells you exactly what you should do right next to where it says it is deprecated. _Please obtain the ConnectionMetaData from the Connection in question or use the Version API to obtain static version information Constructor which uses bindings connection._

Comment: Why would you think the entire class is deprecated?  It does not say that anywhere on that page.

Comment: It even states this fairly clearly right at the top of the document you linked - _Instance of this object should be obtained from the connection, and not created directly._.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is not deprecated, just the constructors. This means that if you want an instance of the class, you should obtain it by calling a method on another class, not by using the constructors, as it says on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Deprecated class]

The content from the page says that the constructor is deprecated. It also says to use another constructor. In this intsance, it says to obtain your `ConnectionMetaData` from the Connection itself.